# How to set DecimalSeparator for a float in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder and my locale is European, so I have a comma as a decimal separator.

I need to convert a double to a decimal point value with a DOT as separator.

I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

`DecimalSeparator` is a global variable, simply set it to the desired character before formatting the `double`, eg:

```cpp
#include <SysUtils.hpp>

System::String FormatWithDot(double value)
{
    System::Char old = Sysutils::DecimalSeparator;
    Sysutils::DecimalSeparator = _D('.');
    System::String s = Sysutils::FloatToStr(value);
    Sysutils::DecimalSeparator = old;
    return s;
}

System::String s = FormatWithDot(123.45);
```

Or, if you need to do this in multiple threads, use the thread-safe version, [`TFormatSettings::DecimalSeparator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.DecimalSeparator):

```cpp
#include <SysUtils.hpp>

System::String FormatWithDot(double value)
{
    Sysutils::TFormatSettings fmt = Sysutils::TFormatSettings::Create();
    fmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');
    return Sysutils::FloatToStr(value, fmt);
}

System::String s = FormatWithDot(123.45);
```

Just note that `DecimalSeparator` only applies to Delphi-based RTL functions like [`FloatToStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.FloatToStr), [`Format()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format), etc.  It does not apply to C++-based functions like `std::(s)printf()`, `std::to_string()`, `std::ostream::operator<<`, etc.  For those, you need to use C++ locales instead.

Comment: That you very much for the effort. I solved it myself by passing fmt to FloatToStr.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the wee hours of the morning myself. You can use:

```
TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
fmt.DecimalSeparator = '.';
```

and then format a double like that:

```
FloatToStr(price, fmt);
```

I hope it helps someone. I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I know this this is a very old thread, but I was facing this problem today. In my case, my solution is this:

```
String DotFormatted(long double value, int numberOfDecimals=2) {
    String result = Format("%." + IntToStr(numberOfDecimals) + "f", ARRAYOFCONST((value)));
    result = StringReplace( result, ",", ".", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);     
    return result; 
}
```

It's equivalent to another one I had in a different language. For me, it's useful because of the numberOfDecimals argument.